# Classic ASP calculation works on IE+ Maxton computer not on Phone's Chrome & Dolphin

Tags: asp-classic

This confuses me quite a bit and I had to remove the whole code for now so the site works, but removing it makes the site look bad.

This code works perfectly on my computers IE and Maxton Browser.

On my Samsung phone's Chrome and Dolphin browsers the result from row 1 is nothin (""). Row two doesn't work either.

I thought all these calculations are done server side, so whatever browser or gadget I use should not make any difference at all? Still it does.

```
'#################  Remove www. ################# 

If left(strDomainName,4)="www." then strDomainNameNoWWW = right(strDomainName,len(strDomainName)-4) 

'#################  Make first letter Uppercase (capital) ################# 

strDomainNameNoWWW=UCase(Left(strDomainNameNoWWW,1)) & LCase(Right(strDomainNameNoWWW, Len(strDomainNameNoWWW) - 1))
```

Is it possible that my web host forward phone browsers automatically to another server and that their "phone server" can't handle these calculations for whatever reason? Or are the calculations done within the browser/gadget or can they be "turned off" in the browser settings?

Could I divide these calculations into 4-6 more simples steps on different rows so that even "the error causing" servers/browsers may understand it? How would that look (this is shared code and I did not write it or know how to rewrite it).

Or could it just be some extra "" marks or lower case upper case letters that is needed on some servers or versions of "server software"?

I am a newbie so please answer so a newbie understands if possible. ;) Thank you!

(The error comes first on row two and says "invalid procedure call or argument right" but from my research checking similar errors on here this should be just fine if the calculations are just done instead of turned off and if the string then is more than nothing, so i believe that the thing t solve is why row 1 produces nothing at all/why calculations are not made)

Comment: This is quite embarrassing but I actually solved it myself now. Should I remove the whole question or shall I leave it in case someone makes the same dumb mistake? :D What i did was that on my phone I wrote the domain name without www. in the address field and on the computer i used www. I didn't make the function so that it would not be confused if there was no www. in the first place, but will correct that now.

Comment: Please don't add the answer to your question. Add the solution as an answer. See : [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite embarrassing but I actually solved it myself now.

What caused the error was that on my phone I had used the domain name without www. in the address field and on the computer i used www. I didn't test the function so that it would work if there was no www. typed in... But I added this as a third row now and now it works:

If not left(strDomainName,4)="www." then strDomainNameNoWWW = strDomainName

Sorry if this wasted someones time.